# perl regex for everything between global

Tags: regex, perl

I have strings formatted as the following.

```
could/MD be/VB said/VBN to/TO be/VB ``/`` duly/RB adopted/VBN ''/'' 
even/RB though/IN 
[ it/PRP ]
```

I want to match the thing after / like MD, VB, VBN, TO, VB, ", RB etc.

This is what I have

```
while(<$FH>)
{
  if($_ =~ /\/(.+?)\s/g)
  {
    print "$1\n";
  }
}
```

If I run it using the above string I get.

```
MD
RB
PRP
```

It is only matching the first instance of my regex even though I am using `/g`
How can I match every single one, including the punctuation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through each line as follows:

```
while (<$FH>) {
  print "$_\n" for /\/(\S+)/g;
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/P5wtDN)

Comment: Can you please explain what the `do { local $/; <$FH> }` is doing?

Comment: It was slurping the file into a scalar, but this approach is more efficient.